# How to assign variable in update statement in pstgresql using Python

Tags: python, postgresql

Please tell me what to write against "usr_created" & id

```py
for row in result:
    var1= row[1]
    var2= row[0]
    cursor.execute("UPDATE new_app_owner.cris_prog_member_activities_stg_sn set  usr_created= var1 where  id = var2 ")
```

Comment: What Python driver are you using?

Comment: A generic solution would be `cursor.execute("UPDATE new_app_owner.cris_prog_member_activities_stg_sn set usr_created= %s where id = %s ", [ row[1], row[2]])`